# A claim on the concurrency of area bisectors of planar convex regions

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, convex-geometry, plane-geometry

We add a little bit to  [On 'fair bisectors' of planar convex regions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/356279/on-fair-bisectors-of-planar-convex-regions) and [Bisectors and partitioning lines for convex regions defined with respect to the moment of inertia](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/437053/bisectors-and-partitioning-lines-for-convex-regions-defined-with-respect-to-the)

**Definitions:** Given a planar convex region C  (could be smooth or polygonal), an area bisector of C
is any line that partitions C  into 2 pieces of equal area. A perimeter bisector is a line that partitions C  into 2 pieces of equal perimeter. Obviously, thru every point on the boundary of C we can draw an area bisector and a perimeter bisector.

**Question:** Are the following claims easy to prove/counter?

- A planar convex region is centrally symmetric if and only if its area bisectors are all concurrent.
- A planar convex region is centrally symmetric if and only if its perimeter bisectors are all concurrent.

Note: Higher dimensional analogs of these claims are easy to state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- A planar convex region is centrally symmetric if and only if its area bisectors are all concurrent.

Yes. Let all area bisectors of our region $K$ pass through a point $O$. Note that any line $\ell$ through $O$ is an area bisector of $K$: otherwise there exists a parallel area bisector (by continuity), and it does not pass through $O$. Assume that $K$ is not $O$-symmetric. It yields that some chord $AB$ through $O$ is not bisected by $O$. Move it slightly to get a chord $A_1B_1$ ($A_1$ close to $A$). The curvilinear triangles $AOA_1$ and $BOB_1$ have unequal area, thus at least one of chords $AB$, $A_1B_1$ is not an area bisector.

Comment: Thanks very much. The same argument seems to prove the other claim as well - A_1B_1 is got by slightly rotating AB about O. Arcs AA_1 and BB_1 will not be of same length if O is not a center of symmetry so both chords AB and A_1B_1 wont be perimeter bisectors.

Comment: I am afraid that for perimeters things are different. The derivative involves the angle between the chord and the tangent

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Shall mark this question as solved and look forward to a settlement to the perimeter issue.